# Amazon transcribe "Operation not found: StartTranscriptionJob"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

- Windows 7 Pro
- PHP 7.0.2
- AWS transcribe API 2017-10-26

Hi,
I'm trying to use Amazon Web Services to transcribe recordings from an IVR (Please leave your name after the tone. etc) using PHP. I can upload the recordings to my AWS bucket (so something is right) but when I try to start the transcription job I get the following error:
"Operation not found: StartTranscriptionJob"

I can get transcription to work using the AWS CLI so my system seems to be set up OK. There is not a lot online about this issue, I've done all the usual Googling and the info isn't very helpful - such as:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/transcribeservice/#TranscribeService.StartTranscriptionJob

Here's my code, the StartTranscriptionJob is at the end:

```
<?php
require 'aws\aws-autoloader.php';
chdir('asr');
$logFile = 'asr.log';
$log = "\n\n".date("d/m/Y H:i:s");

###################
# get the recording
###################

$service   = htmlspecialchars($_GET["service"]);
$recording = htmlspecialchars($_GET["recording"]);

$ftp_server = "ftp.****";
$ftp_username = "****";
$ftp_userpass = "****";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server,7721) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn,'Recordings');
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn,$service);
ftp_get ($ftp_conn , $recording , $recording, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

######################
# Upload to AWS bucket
######################

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('****', '****');
$bucket = 'asr-bucket-test';
$keyname = $recording;

$s3 = new S3Client([
   'profile' => 'default',
   'version' => 'latest',
   'region'  => 'us-west-2',
   'credentials' => $credentials
]);

try {
   // Upload data.
   $result = $s3->putObject([
       'Bucket' => $bucket,
       'Key'    => $keyname,
       'SourceFile'  => '\xampp\htdocs\****.co.uk\asr\\'.$recording,
       'ACL'    => 'public-read'
   ]);

   // Print the URL to the object.
   $log.= "\n".$result['ObjectURL'] . PHP_EOL;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
   $log.= "\n".$e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

############
# Transcribe
############

try {
  $result = $s3->StartTranscriptionJob([
  'LanguageCode' => 'en-US', // REQUIRED
  'Media' => [ 
    'MediaFileUri' => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/asr-bucket-test/'.$recording, 
  ],
  'MediaFormat' => 'wav', // REQUIRED
  'OutputBucketName' => $bucket,
  'Settings' => [
  #  'ChannelIdentification' => true || false,
    'MaxSpeakerLabels' => 5,
  #  'ShowSpeakerLabels' => true || false,
  #  'VocabularyName' => $recording
  ],
  'TranscriptionJobName' => 'test_job', // REQUIRED
  ]);
  $log.="\n".$result;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $log.="\nError: Cannot start transcripion job " . $e->getMessage();
}

file_put_contents($logFile, $log,FILE_APPEND);
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `S3Client` to start the transcription:

```
$result = $s3->StartTranscriptionJob
```

Per the error message, S3 doesn't support the `StartTranscriptionJob` operation.  You need to setup and use the `TranscribeServiceClient`.

You linked to the AWS SDK docs for Go, but your code is PHP. Relevant docs for PHP:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.TranscribeService.TranscribeServiceClient.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new TranscribeServiceClient and then connect through that. Here's a snippet from my working code:

```
    $transcribe = new Aws\TranscribeService\TranscribeServiceClient([
        'region'  => $region,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => $accessKey,
            'secret' => $secretKey,
        ],
    ]);

    //print_r($transcribe);

    $result = $transcribe->startTranscriptionJob([
        'LanguageCode' => $languageCode, // REQUIRED
        'Media' => [ // REQUIRED
            'MediaFileUri' => $mediaURI,
        ],
        'MediaFormat' => $fileExt, // REQUIRED
        'OutputBucketName' => $bucketName,
        'Settings' => [
            'ChannelIdentification' => false,
            'MaxSpeakerLabels' => 5,
            'ShowSpeakerLabels' => true,
            'VocabularyName' => '',
        ],
        'TranscriptionJobName' => $fileName . "-" . date('Ymd-his') // REQUIRED
    ]);
```